# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I installed Anaconda and Python on Windows 10 without errors. I tried to run an example from scrapy shell "url". I got the following error:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "d:\bld\scrapy_1572360424769_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Demo\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe" shell http://blog.adnansiddiqi.me/write-your-first-web-crawler-in-python-scrapy/ '